# Automatically inline CSS from a CSS-file (jquery? ajax? php?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, inline

For reasons we dont need to get in to, I need to put the content of a CSS-file into the style tags of a html-page. I want to do it automatically, so I need to read the CSS file and put it's content in my style tag in my header.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Atleast you should have a scratch on your file.

Comment: Wow thanks for the helpful comments everyone. I'm not asking for anyone to do this for me, I'm asking for some input or tips to get me on my way. I have not written any code because I don't know where to start or how to approach this problem.

Kevin: If you actually read my question you will notice that it's not just a matter of copy and pasting some styles from my CSS-file into my html. I wan't to read the CSS with javascript/jquery and output it dynamically.

Comment: Write in the question that you want to do it via jQuery ajax, then someone will help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best would be if you used PHP, django, ASP.net or something from this family.
For PHP I would do like this:

```
<style id="Something">
<?php readfile("http://example.com/some/style.css"); ?>
</style>
```

But if you want to use jQuery, try this:

```
<style id="Something"></style>
<script type="text/javascript">
var request = $.ajax({
  url: "stylesheet.css",
});
request.done(function( msg ) {
  $( "style#Something" ).html( msg );
});
request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
  alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this. However, I'm not stuck to javascript or jQuery, I just thought it would be the best approach. How would you do this with PHP, if you think that's a better option?

Comment: OH! It was THAT easy!
Thanks!