# jQuery: Is there a way to grab a HTML element's external CSS and append to its "Style" attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Basically what i want to do is grab all CSS that is referenced in an external stylesheet e.g  `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/General.css">` and append it to any existing styling for each HTML element in my page. (make all CSS inline)

The reason for this is because i need to call `.html()` to grab a  div and send to server to be made into a PDF. The downside with this tool is that it only recognises inline CSS.

Are there any ways to do this?

Edit: the question that was linked to mine as a "possible duplicate" spoke only of putting everything in the `<style>` tag. while that may be useful, im mainly concerned with loading into the `style=""` html atribute

Comment: You would need to loop through the CSS rules and use querySelectorAll to do it. I do not have time to make a working demo.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automatically inline CSS from a CSS-file (jquery? ajax? php?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25260263/automatically-inline-css-from-a-css-file-jquery-ajax-php)

Comment: See the [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the past I've used `window.getComputedStyle(element);` for this purpose. It will return a map of all styles applied to the element, which you can then loop across and apply as an inline style. I wouldn't apply them to the actual DOM if you can avoid it (just create a document fragment / concat it in the style of the string you're sending up). It will be a performance nightmare to actually apply that many inline styles to an element.

Using computed styles still might not be enough, as there are vendor prefixed styles in the user agent stylesheet. If you send up markup from Firefox to PhantomJS(webkit), you will obviously not get the same looking element.